# Calculations with JavaScript without submitting the form

Tags: javascript

I have a couple of buttons on my form that do mileage calculations and the other updates the cost. These work as expected but they also submit the form.

Here are the fields:

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Miles, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "number" } })
     <button onclick="roundTrip()">Round Trip?</button>&nbsp;
     <button onclick="updatedPrice()">Update Price</button>

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "price" } })
```

Here is my JavaScript:

```
    function updatedPrice() {
        var price = $("#number").val() * @calcMiles;
        var calPrice = price.toFixed(2)
        $("#price").val(calPrice);
    }

    function roundTrip() {
        var calc = $("#number").val() * 2;
        $("#number").val(calc);
    }
```

Maybe I need to do a replace? Not sure why it submits when I click either one of these.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: for this to be a question, there should still be a form to be deactivated here  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can just not put them inside a <form>. However if you want the user to be able to submit the form, you can either add `type="button"` to the button or assign the event handler with JS/jQuery instead of an inline `onclick` (which is bad practice anyway). Like `$('#btnTrip').on('click', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /* price calculation here */ });`

Comment: Duplicate: [How to prevent buttons from submitting forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms)